# How to configure Spring to support @Cacheable annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching

I have a very simple method which I annotated @Cacheable, expecting it will execute only once per parameter sent to it, but it doesn't wirk as expected and executes each time. 
To simplify things, let's say my method is the following:

```
      @Cacheable(value = "test")
      public int someMethod(int val){
         return val++;
      }
```

And I invoke it twice as following:

```
    int result1 = someMethod(1);
    int result2 = someMethod(1);
```

As I understood, I should make some configuration so it will work as expected, probably at xml. What is that apropriate confuguration?

Comment: ...because you call it with different arguments?

Comment: OOPS, of course with both times same par. fixed

Comment: ...because you're invoking the method like a regular Java method call, without getting Spring involved?

Comment: I'm very new to Spring, what do you mean by involving Spring?

Comment: Well, I don't know Spring at all. If you write `someMethod(1)`, you are invoking the method like any other method. How would you expect Spring to intercept this call and stop the method being invoked.

Comment: I get what you mean. I'll rephrase my question. Thanks!

Comment: Spring is not involved at all here, you should invoke this via spring, and also enable caching if you want this to work.

Comment: To see a working example have a look at the guides provided: http://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring boot, you should set `@EnableCaching` annotation in your config file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCaching
public class Application {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        // configure and return an implementation of Spring's CacheManager SPI
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("default")));
        return cacheManager;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

then you should register `CacheManager` bean. See the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html)

Your spring component with `@Cacheable` annotation which value should be present in `caches` in your `CacheManager` bean.

```
@Service
public class CacheableService {
    @Cacheable(value="default")
    public int sum(int i,int q){
        System.out.println("called");
        return i+q;
    }
}
```